# How do I create a top fixed floating navigation bar with responsive measurements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I want to make a floating navigation bar at the top, and when it reaches a low resolution (600) apply media queries, and hide the options inside a bar icon or inside the logo. I manage to mount everything but when I scroll the page, the nav bar goes up to the top of the page.

I appreciate if you could tell me what I need to add to the code to make it work or if you have more effective ideas, I would appreciate your wisdom. Thank you

[image: Picture]

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topmenu") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topmenu";
  }
}
```

```css
/** Topmenu Style **/

.topmenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  margin: 23px;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 11px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 14px -7px #065158;
  z-index: 10;
}

.topmenu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #808080;
  font-weight: 400;
  transition: 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.topmenu a:hover {
  color: #15a5b2;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.topmenu .icon {
  display: none;
}

.contact {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.active {
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/**** Media Queries ***/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topmenu a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topmenu a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topmenu.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topmenu.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topmenu.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="wow animated fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0s">
  <ul class="">
    <div class="topmenu" id="myTopnav">
      <img class="" style="float:left; padding-right: 100px; " src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
      <a class="home" href="#home">Inicio</a>
      <a href="#contact">Sobre</a>
      <a href="#about">Trabajo</a>
      <a href="#price">Precio</a>
      <a class="contact" href="#contact">Contacto</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please edit the snippet demo above to show the problem. You may need to add some page content to show scroll behavior. See [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Protip: Use `classList.includes('topmenu')` and `classList.add('responsive')` rather than what you have, which will only match that exact string. If you ever add other classes for styling or whatever your script will break.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Dottemo/9u7dnLgt/4/ , Hi! , here you can review the code, if you click on the menu in the middle of the page, it will go up, when it should keep the position it is in and show the options

Comment: Sorry, where i use classList.includes('topmenu') and classList.add('responsive') ?

Comment: It would replace your `className` check. I asked you to edit the snippet above, not link us to another website.